# How can I handle merge option in GitHub using GitLab API

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I have to block the merge request when the pipeline run is not recent (at least not run within 10 hours or so).

Restrict merge option using GitLab API.

Answer (score 0):

To restrict the merge option using GitLab API based on the condition of a recent pipeline run, you can use GitLab's Merge Request API in combination with the Pipeline API.

First, you will need to retrieve the latest pipeline for the branch associated with the merge request. You can use the Pipeline API to retrieve this information.